# WebService Within a Web Application

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, web-applications, nested

I have this project developed by some goofball who decided to nest a dependent WebService within the Web Application that uses it. This has caused problems with publishing changes because you can't update the WebService without Publishing your changes first, and you can't Publish the changes without the WebService being updated at the publishing location. It's totally paradoxical.

Any suggestions on how to remedy this simply? I'm thinking it might be best to somehow extract the WebService out into a separate project which can be published independently (this is best practice after all, isn't it?). Also note that I have updated the project to .NET 4 which has the option to use a WCF Service instead, however if this would require a major reworking of the project, then I would like to keep things as simple as possible.

It's difficult to provide any code to illustrate this problem, but here is the basic hierarchy of the project.

```
Solution
    Project
        WebService
            MyService 'This is a reference to the Web Service
        Service
            MyService.asmx 'This is the actual code for the Web Service
        [Other Code Pages within the project]
```

**EDIT: What if I did this?** This way they could be compiled and published independently of each other.

```
Solution
    Project - App
        Web Reference
            MyService 'This is a reference to the Web Service
        [Other Code Pages within the project]
    Project - Service
        Service
            MyService.asmx 'This is the actual code for the Web Service
```

The only remaining decision (assuming this is a recommended approach) would be whether to create a WCF Service Library or WCF Service Application? *(Remember, this service is only used by this one app and is not shared by any other).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely extract the web service into a new project.

In addition, if there is other "shared" code (classes, modules) that is common between the projects, you have a couple of choices, depending on how much code needs to be shared:

1) Link the source files from one project or the other (so that you only have a single physical copy of the class)

2) Create a DLL project that each of the projects references and then move the shared code to that project.

3) (Obviously) Duplicate the code in each project.

Comment: It's worth noting that this particular web service is only used for this one app. As for a shared DLL, I'm familiar with this concept with respect to libraries/assemblies, but have no idea how to make this work with a web service.

Comment: Your approach is definitely what I would suggest. For the WCF decision, I suggest that you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423065/what-is-the-purpose-of-wcf-service-library